# Python regex negative lookahead matching where it shouldn't

Tags: python, regex

Example first:

```py
import re

details = 'input1 mem001 output1 mem005 data2 mem002 output12 mem006'
input_re = re.compile(r'(?!output[0-9]*) mem([0-9a-f]+)')
print(input_re.findall(details))
# Out: ['001', '005', '002', '006']
```

I am using negative lookahead to extract the hex part of the `mem` entries that are not preceded by an `output`, however as you can see it fails. The desired output should be: `['001', '002']`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r"(?<!output\d) mem([0-9a-f]+)", details)`

Comment: Can there be multiple digits following word `output`?

Comment: This is a minimal example, in my real example yes they can be multiple digits following. @ArtyomVancyan this works for the minimal example but not when there is a variable number of digits.
Let me update the example to reflect a bit more my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex in `findall`:

```bash
\b(?!output\d+)\w+\s+mem([a-zA-F\d]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D8hRDV/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?!output\d+)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `output` and 1+ digits ahead
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `mem([a-zA-F\d]+)`: Match `mem` followed by 1+ of any hex character

**Code:**

```py
import re
s = 'input1 mem001 output1 mem005 data2 mem002 output12 mem006'
print( re.findall(r'\b(?!output\d+)\w+\s+mem([a-zA-F\d]+)', s) )
```

**Output:**

```
['001', '002']
```

Comment: It seems to work, but why does it need the word boundary?

Comment: If there is no word boundary then negative lookahead will succeed by matching `utput1` as `\w+` can match from the middle of a word also.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an easier approach is to split it up in 2 regular expressions ?
First filter out anything that starts with output and is followed by mem like so

```
output[0-9]* mem([0-9a-f]+)
```

If you filter this out it would result in

```
input1 mem001 data2 mem002
```

When you have filtered them out just search for mem again

```
mem([0-9a-f]+)
```

That would result in your desired output

```
['001', '002']
```

Maybe not an answer to the original question, but it is a solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's understand why your original regex doesn't work:

A regex encapsulates two pieces of information: a description of a location within a text, and a description of what to capture from that location. Your original regex tells the regex matcher: "Find a location within the text where the following characters are not 'output'+digits but they are ' mem'+alphanumetics". Think of the logic of that expression: if the matcher finds a location in the text where the following characters are ' mem'+alphanumerics, then, in particular, the following characters are not 'output'+digits. Your look ahead does not add anything to the exoression.

What you really need is to tell the matcher: "Find a location in the text where the following characters are ' mem'+alphanumerics, and the **previous** characters are not 'output'+digits. So what you really need is a look-behind, not look-ahead.

@ArtyomVancyan proposed a good regex with a look-behind, and it could easily be modified to what you need: instead of a single digit after the 'output', you want potentially more digits, so just put an asterisk (*) after the '\d'.

Comment: Just fyi `(?<!output\d*)` will generate an error in python